# How to numerate the Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, numbering

I've tried several things but nothing seems to work. Can someone tell me what is wrong? All I want is to have numbers in front of each of my sources, such as

[1] source 1

[2] source 2

[3] etc.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[numbib,nottoc,numindex]{tocbibind}

\renewcommand\bibname{Källhänvisningar}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
\makeatother

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

  \bibitem{} Ver Hoef, Jay M. \& Boveng, Peter L. 2007. {\em Quasi-poisson vs. Negative binomial regression: How should we model overdispersed count data?.} Ecology, 88(11), 2766-2772.

  \end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This would be the default with `biblatex`.

Comment: Then why do you redefine \@biblabel to do nothing?

Comment: @Bernard - You mean instead of \usepackage[numbib,nottoc,numindex]{tocbibind} ?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer - Ok, how should I write \@biblabel to get what I want?

Comment: Simply remove the line.

Comment: I mean instead of using  the `thebibliography`environment. `tocbibind` is used to decide whether  the bibbliography, the index,&c., will be mentioned in the toc, and how.  With `biblatex+biber`  (or `+bibtex`), you write a `.bib` file, mention you'll use this file  with `\addbibresource` , choose a style, and code `\printbibliography`. The formatting is automatic.

Comment: @Ulrike Fisher - Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Some comments and suggestions:

- If you want bibliographic items numbered, follow Ulrike Fischer's advice and get rid of the `\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}` statement which, in fact, is what's suppressing the showing of the numbers.
- I take it that you're building the bibliography by hand. If that's the case, do yourself a favor and (a) load the `natbib` citation management package with the option `numbers` and (b) change the `\bibitem` instruction from

  ```
  \bibitem{}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \bibitem[Ver Hoef and Boveng(2007)]{verhoef-boveng:2007}
  ```

  Doing this accomplishes two purposes. First, it lets you create numeric-style citation call-outs in the body of the paper using, you guessed it, `\cite` instructions. Second, should you one day decide you would rather generate authoryear-style citation call-outs, all you would need to do is change the instruction `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` to `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}` and re-run LaTeX.

A final exhortation: Do yourself an even bigger favor and learn how to create formatted bibliographies not by hand, but with the use of a software tool such as BibTeX or `biblatex`. For starters, you might create a file called, say, `mybib.bib` with the following contents:

```
@article{verhoef-boveng:2007,
    author  = {Jay M. Ver Hoef and Peter L. Boveng},
    title   = {{Quasi‐Poisson} vs.\ negative binomial regression: 
               How should we model overdispersed count data?},
    journal = {Ecology},
    year    = 2007,
    volume  = 88,
    number  = 11,
    pages   = {2766-2772},
}
```

Next, choose a suitable bibliography style -- journals often provide their own house styles -- put it in the argument of a `\bibliographystyle` instruction, place a `\cite{verhoef-boveng:2007}` in a suitable place in your bibliography, and run LaTeX, BibTeX (or `biber`, if you're using the `biblatex` package rather than `natbib`), and LaTeX twice more -- and, voilà! -- you have both a citation call-out and a formatted bibliographic entry.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{verhoef-boveng:2007,
    author  = {Jay M. Ver Hoef and Peter L. Boveng},
    title   = {{Quasi‐Poisson} vs.\ negative binomial regression: 
               How should we model overdispersed count data?},
    journal = {Ecology},
    year    = 2007,
    volume  = 88,
    number  = 11,
    pages   = {2766-2772},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib,numindex]{tocbibind}

\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\addto\extrasswedish{\def\bibname{Källhänvisningar}}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % choose a suitable bib style

\begin{document}
\cite{verhoef-boveng:2007}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```